# decode FLAC file with avcodec_decode_audio4 not work well

Tags: c, ffmpeg, pcm, flac

I use `FFmpeg` to decode my `flac` file and write it to `pcm` file, then use GoldenWave to play it with `pcm signed 16bit, little endian, mono` and the total play time is ok.

I doubt i write the 2 channel file in one place, but i don't know how to get every signal channel and write it to `pcm` file.

any help? thank you.

```
while (av_read_frame(fmt_ctx, &pkt) >= 0) {
            AVPacket orig_pkt = pkt;
            do {
                ret = decode_packet(&got_frame, 0);
                if (ret < 0)
                    break;
                pkt.data += ret;
                pkt.size -= ret;
            } while (pkt.size > 0);
            av_free_packet(&orig_pkt);
        }

        pkt.data = NULL;
        pkt.size = 0;
        do {
            decode_packet(&got_frame, 1);
            LOG("flush cached frames");
        } while (got_frame);



static int decode_packet(int *got_frame, int cached)
{
    int ret = 0;
    int decoded = pkt.size;

    *got_frame = 0;

    if (pkt.stream_index == audio_stream_idx) {
        ret = avcodec_decode_audio4(audio_dec_ctx, frame, got_frame, &pkt);
        if (ret < 0) {
            LOG("Error decoding audio frame (%s)\n", av_err2str(ret));
            return ret;
        }

        decoded = FFMIN(ret, pkt.size);

        if (*got_frame) {
            size_t unpadded_linesize = frame->nb_samples * av_get_bytes_per_sample(audio_dec_ctx->sample_fmt);
            //decode packet  nb_samples:4608, xx:2, unpadded_linesize: 9216
            LOG("decode packet  nb_samples:%d, xx:%d, unpadded_linesize: %d",
                    frame->nb_samples, av_get_bytes_per_sample(audio_dec_ctx->sample_fmt), unpadded_linesize);
            fwrite(frame->extended_data[0], 1, unpadded_linesize, audio_dst_file);

            //int nb_sample = frame->nb_samples;

            //fwrite(frame->extended_data[0], 1, nb_sample, audio_dst_file);
            //fwrite(frame->extended_data[0] + nb_sample, 1, nb_sample, audio_dst_file);

        }
    }

    if (*got_frame && api_mode == API_MODE_NEW_API_REF_COUNT)
        av_frame_unref(frame);

    return decoded;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't describe the problem you're having, but from what you're writing, I see two problems:

1. you're not checking the raw audio format of the frame, see frame->[format](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/structAVFrame.html#aed14fa772ce46881020fd1545c86432c) (or audio_dec_ctx->[sample_fmt](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/structAVCodecContext.html#a1bdba69ea111e2a9d03fdaa7a46a4c45)). You're writing it as if it were [AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S16](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__lavu__sampfmts.html#ggaf9a51ca15301871723577c730b5865c5aea6132df57aebc3f76e10665395c46af), but you're not checking that it is
2. your unpadded_linesize is not multiplied by the number of channels (see e.g. frame->[channels](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/structAVFrame.html#a58c663568a99c1477c163e64858b3fef))

Comment: In fact, this is a piece of FFmpeg example code in demuxering_decodeing.c. and modify `got_packet` part  replace the unpadded_linesize with `frame->linesize[0]` then it's work. thank you